# Trying to join two models, not sure what the appropriate active record association should be

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, rails-activerecord

I have two models- Volunteer and Registration.

Volunteers are more stable, but Registrants will come and go. I am trying to assign a new registration to a volunteer, by having a foreign key in my Registration model  for the volunteer_id.

I've looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32201949/what-is-the-behaviour-of-create-join-table-of-activerecordmigration) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21083625/rails-joining-multiple-tables) and ended up creating a join table that includes the ids of both registrations and volunteers:

```
class CreateJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_join_table :registrations, :volunteers do |t|
      t.index [:registration_id, :volunteer_id], name: :reg_vol_index
      t.index [:volunteer_id, :registration_id], name: :vol_reg_index
    end
  end
end
```

In my two models I'm not entirely sure what to list the associations as - I've read about has_many, belongs_to, and has_many_and_belongs_to- as well as t.reference.

I'm only wanting to be able to assign a volunteer id to a registration.

Can anyone help clarify what type of association is best?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Join Table already created you can use `has_and_belongs_to_many` association for both models.

volunteer.rb:

```
class Volunteer < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :registrations
end
```

registration.rb:

```
class Registration < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :volunteers
end
```

This will allow you to access registrations through a volunteer (`volunteer.registrations`) and volunteers through a registration (`registration.volunteers`)

See here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association